# How can I iterate over a list with two different criteria?

Tags: python, list, class, for-loop, minimum

Hey guys I'm facing a problem with a for loop  that I couldn't find a solution for online.

Lets say I create two classes, one for people and one for animals. By setting up  a loop method for the animal class that iterates over a list of Peoples ages I wanted to find the owner for each pet which has the same age or at least the smallest age gap (this example is just for making the code look simpler). I used a `min()` function in order to find the person with the smallest age gap which works fine.

But what if I added one more criteria to the selection process? For example I would like to assign the animal only to those people who own less than 3 pets, meaning that even though a person has the smallest age gap, the pet cannot be assigned to that person if it owns already 3 pets. In that case the loop would have to find the next person with the smallest age gap which owns less than 3 pets. In my case A1 would have to be assigned to P1, since it is the person with the smallest age gap which owns less than 3 pets.

Here's my code so far:

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, name, age, pets_owned):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.pets_owned=pets_owned

P1=People("John",16, 1)
P2=People("Alex",10, 4)
P3=People("Anna", 20, 3)


People_List=[P1, P2, P3]
People_Age=[P1.age, P2.age, P3.age]

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age, owner):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.owner=owner

    def find(self):
        closest_age = (min(People_Age, key=lambda x: abs(x - self.age)))
        for a in People_List:
            if a.age ==closest_age and a.pets_owned<3:
                self.owner=a.name
                a.pets_owned+=1
                break

            elif a.age==closest_age and a.pets_owned >=3:
                pass #this is where I`m stuck


        print(self.owner)


A1=Animal("Snoopy",7,"not_owned_yet")


A1.find()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you aren't going to include certain people because of a criteria, I would pre-filter the incoming list to exclude those people. Basically, instead of using a for loop at all, just filter the list, then find the min, then add the pet.

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, name, age, pets_owned):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.pets_owned=pets_owned

P1=People("John",16, 1)
P2=People("Alex",10, 4)
P3=People("Anna", 20, 3)


People_List=[P1, P2, P3]
People_Age=[P1.age, P2.age, P3.age]

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, age, owner):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.owner=owner

    def find(self):
        people_with_less_than_3 = filter(lambda x: x.pets_owned<3, People_List) # filter the list to only include people that have less than 3 pets
        try:
            person_with_closest_age = min(people_with_less_than_3, key=lambda x: abs(x.age - self.age)) # change this to return a person as well
        except:
            # do something if no person with < 3 pets
        self.owner = person_with_closest_age.name
        print(self.owner)


A1=Animal("Snoopy",7,"not_owned_yet")


A1.find()
```

Comment: Drop the `list` conversion on the first line of find and your solution on Python 3 returns to optimal (a single pass on the list instead of 2 worst case) - this is exactly where generators shine.

Comment: @kabanus nice catch, prolly should add a condition for when there are no people_with_less_than_3, but OP should decide what to do in that case

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Ryan. Great and very simple answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort based on multiple attributes, by having your sorting key return a tuple. In my example, first we sort based on age gap (higher priority), then by the number of pets owned (lower priority). You don't need to use `sorted` like I did, since I'm only using it to demonstrate how sorting works based on multiple attributes. You may want to use `min` with the same key to get the most eligible person. You'll also want to modify `assign_new_owner` to actually assign a new owner rather (using `min`) than print people:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, pets_owned):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pets_owned = pets_owned

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, age {self.age} owns {self.pets_owned} pet(s)."

class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name, age, owner=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.owner = owner

    def assign_new_owner(self, people):
        sorted_people = sorted(people, key=lambda p: (abs(p.age - self.age), p.pets_owned))
        for person in sorted_people:
            print(person)

def main():

    people = [
        Person("Alex", 16, 0),
        Person("Nigel", 15, 2),
        Person("Fred", 10, 3),
        Person("Tom", 10, 0),
        Person("Tyler", 15, 0),
        Person("Sam", 15, 1)
        ]

    animal = Animal("Snoopy", 10)
    animal.assign_new_owner(people)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
 Tom, age 10 owns 0 pet(s).
 Fred, age 10 owns 3 pet(s).
 Tyler, age 15 owns 0 pet(s).
 Sam, age 15 owns 1 pet(s).
 Nigel, age 15 owns 2 pet(s).
 Alex, age 16 owns 0 pet(s).
```

EDIT: After using min, the code might look more like this:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age, pets_owned):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pets_owned = pets_owned

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, age {self.age} owns {self.pets_owned} pet(s)."

class Animal:

    def __init__(self, name, age, owner=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.owner = owner

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}, age {self.age} is owned by {self.owner.name if self.owner else 'no one'}."

    def assign_new_owner(self, people):
        self.owner = min(people, key=lambda p: (abs(p.age - self.age), p.pets_owned))

def main():

    people = [
        Person("Alex", 16, 0),
        Person("Nigel", 15, 2),
        Person("Fred", 10, 3),
        Person("Tom", 10, 0),
        Person("Tyler", 15, 0),
        Person("Sam", 15, 1)
        ]

    animal = Animal("Snoopy", 10)
    print(animal)
    animal.assign_new_owner(people)
    print(animal)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Snoopy, age 10 is owned by no one.
Snoopy, age 10 is owned by Tom.
```